# Entity Framework Power Tools - cannot connect to Oracle

Tags: entity-framework, odp.net

I have just installed Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 into Visual Studio 2013. I am running a .NET framework 4.5 project, using Entity Framework code first with an Oracle database. I have installed the latest ODP.NET from Oracle (version 12), including the EF drivers, and I have Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework referenced in my project.

This set up allows me to run my project and read and access data from the Oracle database. It all works fine. My problem is when I try to use the Entity Framework Power Tools. I can specify a connection using the Oracle database name and credentials, and the dialog says 'Test Connection succeeded'. However, after clicking the next button, I get the following error:

**System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The store provider factory type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface.**

I am confused because my project is able to use the installed ODP.NET as is to communicate with the Oracle database via Entity Framework. Most of the research I have done on the WWW suggests there should be a problem with versions and the contents of the web.config - but if this is the case surely I wouldn't be able to use EF with Oracle in my project without errors?

Is it just the case that the Power Tools do not work with Oracle?

Cheers!
Martin

Comment: It's trying to use System.Data.OracleClient which is NOT ODP.NET. Is there a way to tell it which Data Source to use so you can tell it to use ODP.NET?

Comment: Thanks Christian. You were quite right. Just Microsoft drivers were present in the list of providers...I installed Oracle Tools for Visual Studio, and this added ODP.NET as an available provider in the Power Tools.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian says in his comment, you need to install ODP.NET as a provider that Power Tools can use. I did this by installing Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.